# MYSQL - Returning errors if condition fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Good evening guys, I'm faced with some MYSQL queries and have been scratching my head for the past day looking for solutions and testing various other solutions.

Before explaining my issue: This is my current code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {

  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO participants (name, pin, nric, contact, email, address)
        SELECT $name, $pin, $nric, $contact, $email, $address 
        FROM users 
        WHERE (contact=$contact AND time >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 0";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully"; 
} else {   
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
} 
mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

So, what I'm trying to accomplish here is, I am trying to insert these users information through a form, and if they had previously submitted within the past day, they are not allowed to submit again until 24 hours have passed. With the query written above, if the users fails the condition (Which is if their mobile number are found in the database, and the timestamp is still within 24hours), their records will not be saved again. However, this still returns a "New record created successfully", instead of an error, how can I format my code so that it returns an error instead of New record successfully created?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Thanks! utilizing mysqli.affected-rows had allowed me to receive the input of either "0" rows affected, or "1" rows affected, which I then was able to use to throw out validations.

Answer (score -2):

If you want check some where condition then don't add  having clause
having clause in you case  return  some unpredictable result

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO participants (name, pin, nric, contact, email, address)
    SELECT $name, $pin, $nric, $contact, $email, $address 
    FROM users 
    WHERE (contact=$contact AND time >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

the use of having clase without proper aggragtion function and group by prouce row result also when  where condition fail.